# Che senso ha il verbo "incassare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs

Ecco il titolo di una recente [notizia apparsa su Euronews](https://it.euronews.com/2020/08/24/trump-incassa-la-nomination-presidenziale-repubblicana) (grassetto mio):

> Trump **incassa** la nomination presidenziale repubblicana

Ho letto tutte le accezioni del [verbo "incassare" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/incassare), ma non mi sembra che nessuna abbia senso nel contesto dell'articolo. Le definizioni che ho trovato su altri dizionari sono simili.

Potreste spiegare cosa significa, facendo magari qualche altro esempio di uso in cui questo verbo abbia lo stesso senso (se veramente si tratta di un utilizzo con una certa diffusione)?

---

## Aggiornamento:

Aggiungo altri esempi di uso di "incassare" in cui penso che il senso possa essere lo stesso (sono riuscita a trovarli grazie ai commenti che mi hanno dato indizi su cosa possa significare   e sul fatto che questo utilizzo possa avere una certa diffusione). Da notare che si tratta sempre di linguaggio giornalistico (il grassetto è sempre mio):

> - Dopo **aver incassato** la vittoria sul suo decreto, il vicepremier non molla ([La Stampa](https://www.lastampa.it/politica/2019/08/06/news/salvini-apre-le-danze-sulla-tav-voteremo-mozioni-a-favore-del-progresso-1.37306093)).
> - **Incassato** il Trofeo Tim, a casa Inter si respira un grande ottimismo ([Il Giorno](https://www.ilgiorno.it/milano/sport/2012/07/22/747747-inter-Coutinho.shtml)).
> - E l'impressione è che ora servirà un mezzo miracolo per **incassare** la Coppa ([Il giornale di Vicenza](https://m.ilgiornaledivicenza.it/home/sport/asiago-hockey/l-asiago-spicca-il-volo-ma-rouen-lo-riporta-a-terra-1.4556901?pag=1)).
> - Nel 1977 a diventare EGOT è l’attrice Helen Hayes (nella foto con Gary Cooper), che quell’anno vince il Grammy dopo **aver già incassato** l’Oscar nel 1932, il Tony nel 1947 e l’Emmy nel 1953 ([Sky](https://tg24.sky.it/spettacolo/cinema/approfondimenti/vincitori-egot#00)).

Comment: Non trovo questo significato  di dizionari, per cui potrei sbagliarmi.

Comment: Non si potrebbe considerare semplicemente un uso figurato del significato di “riscuotere” (a sua volta nel senso di “Prendere, ricevere denaro dovuto”)?

Comment: Sì, @DaG: questo l'aveva detto Hachi nei suoi commenti, ma adesso vedo che sono stati cancellati e ha aggiunto di non esserne sicuro perché non si trova sui dizionari. Adesso non so cosa stia succedendo che il Treccani è inaccessibile, ma quando ho visto che quella accezione faceva riferimento a una somma di denaro, ho pensato troppo subito che non aveva senso nel contesto. Ha anche detto che questo uso figurato ha una certa diffusione, ma è stato cancellato pure questo.

Comment: Non ho visto i commenti prima che fossero cancellati. A orecchio, mi suona come di un luogo comune del linguaggio giornalistico (come “la partita si conclude con un nulla di fatto” o “il tragico bilancio è destinato a salire”).

Comment: Può darsi, @DaG: tutti gli altri esempi che sono riuscita a trovare in cui penso che il senso sia lo stesso provengono dal linguaggio giornalistico.

Comment: Segnalo anche la locuzione collegata "andare all'incasso".

Comment: Ha un senso figurato simile, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica? Neanche questo si trova sui dizionari.

Comment: @Charo, no - indica il momento "precedente" dell'azione: chi è in posizione di ottenere eventualmente un premio/vantaggio o simili, "va all'incasso" appunto per incassare/realizzare.

Comment: Sì, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: questo potevo immaginarlo dal costrutto con "andare a" (in senso figurato). Volevo chiedere se in questa espressione "incasso" ha un senso figurato simile a quello di "incassare" riportato nella risposta perché tale senso figurato non appare alla voce "incasso" dei dizionari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'esempio calzante è quello di *incassare un assegno* (*cashing a check* in inglese americano).

<sup>Piccola divagazione: la parola *cassa* in senso economico-bancario ha origine a Firenze ed è stata esportata in tutta Europa.</sup>

Il senso figurato nel titolo giornalistico è “ottenere qualcosa” che può essere dovuto o meritato, ma anche non dovuto né meritato.

Esempio (fittizio): “Il [Borgorosso FC](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Il_presidente_del_Borgorosso_Football_Club) incassa il pareggio” può significare che la squadra del Borgorosso non ha avuto grandi meriti nell'ottenere il risultato di parità. Ecco un [esempio non fittizio](https://www.genova24.it/2020/02/pari-con-il-toro-il-genoa-primavera-incassa-un-punto-utile-231004/): “Il Genoa primavera incassa un punto utile”.

Al contrario, come riportato nel dizionario Treccani, *incassare un gol* significa subirlo.

Nel caso del titolo su Trump, si vuole sottolineare che la *nomination* era attesa e dovuta e che, ora, Trump può dedicarsi ad altro (la campagna elettorale).

Questa accezione di *incassare* è gergo giornalistico. Non credo di aver mai sentito qualcuno (che non fosse un giornalista in servizio) adoperarla.

Comment: La cosa curiosa è che nei dizionari appare l'accezione di "incassare" come subire qualcosa senza ribellarsi, senza accusare il colpo. In questo senso si può dire "incassare un insulto" o "incassare un gol". Ma in tutti gli esempi della domanda e di questa risposta (eccetto quello del gol) quello che si incassa è qualcosa di positivo per la persona, squadra, ecc. che lo riceve.

Comment: @Charo Mi pare che l'inizio della risposta sia abbastanza chiaro, o no? Aggiungi il capoverso finale e avrai ciò che cerchi: è gergo giornalistico.

Comment: Non mi sembra ci sia niente da aggiungere, @egreg: era soltanto un commento. Volevo semplicemente dire che personalmente mi sembra curioso che, nel linguaggio giornalistico, si sia in certo senso deciso che, nello stesso modo in cui si può incassare qualcosa di negativo (un gol, un'offesa, ...), si può anche incassare qualcosa di positivo (una vittoria, un trofeo, un punto, ...). E la risposta è chiara: il mio commento precedente non voleva essere in nessun modo una critica alla risposta, era semplicemente un'osservazione di qualcosa che mi pare curioso. Mi dispiace se non si è capito.

Comment: @Charo - sono d’accordo con te. È curioso che i dizionari riportino soltanto il senso figurato di incassare in termini negativi e non viceversa. Aggiungerei che l’espressione è entrata anche nel linguaggio comune. L’espressione “passare/andare  all’incasso” come notato in un commento non è usata solo dai giornalisti.

Comment: Può darsi che sia così, @Hachi: secondo la mia esperienza, il gergo giornalistico, soprattutto se usato in televisione, ha una certa influenza nel modo in come finiscono per esprimersi molte persone.

Comment: Questo senso è una naturale estensione figurata di “incassare un assegno, un pagamento etc.” e quindi evidentemente non richiede una spiegazione a sé. “Incassare un gol” e simili, invece, è proprio un nuovo significato (nel senso letterale non si mette nella cassa una cosa negativa).

Comment: @Hachi, posso chiederti di che parte d'Italia sei? A Roma non mi pare di aver mai sentito “passare/andare all’incasso”, ma non dubito che altrove si usi, visto che già in due lo notate.

Comment: @DaG - Io tra casa e lavoro mi muovo tra Veneto e Lombardia principalmente.

Comment: Può darsi che sia così, @DaG. A me, però, queste cose non risultano mai tanto ovvie.

Comment: @Charo: Hai ragione, non sono cose ovvie. Come vedi, anche fra italiani abbiamo dubbi e oscillazioni regionali, dii registro etc.

Comment: Grazie, @Hachi.

Comment: Personalmente, da un po' di tempo sono arrivata alla conclusione che la cosa più sensata da fare è non tenere conto dei downvote di cui non riesco in nessun modo a capire o nemmeno a intuire la ragione. Per favore, ricordatevi di questa [discussione sul sito Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1337/), che in questo momento è riaperta per si qualcuno vuole aggiungere qualcosa in più.

Comment: Va bene, @DaG: a quanto pare, però, alcuni utenti non sono d'accordo che questo sia il significato (o forse è un'altra cosa, non so)... Boh!